# Suppose that $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, that $f(1)=1$ and $f(7)=5$. Show that there exists $c\in(0,4)$ such that $f'(c)=\frac{2}{3}$.

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, mean-value-theorem

So, it's obvious that using the Mean Value Theorem you can ascertain that there exists $\alpha\in(1,7)$ such that
$$f'(\alpha)=\frac{f(7)-f(1)}{7-1}=\frac{4}{6}=\frac{2}{3}.$$
What I don't understand is how I'm meant to narrow the interval of $\alpha$ to $(0,4)$ from $(1,7)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Available content: Everything in Spivak's Calculus up to and including derivatives and their applications. You aren't meant to use integrals or anything more advanced for this.

Comment: There is probably a mistake, you cannot narrow $\alpha$ to $(0,4)$ in general (as a counterexample, take $f$ differentiable such that $f(x)=1$ for every $x \leq 5$ and $f(7)=5$).

Comment: I thought something was up with the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true, take for exemple $f=1$ on $]-\infty,6]$ and then connect $(6,1)$ and $(7,5)$ in a smooth way.